# Search Duplicate numbers in a integer array

Tags: java

I want to find the duplicate numbers in the array.
For this am comparing in the following way, but I am not able to get the desired output

The new array should contain numbers without duplicacy.

I have tried the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

              int[] a={1,2,3,6,3,5,7,3,9,7};

              int[] k=new int[a.length];

              for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){

                     for(int j=1;j<a.length;j++){
                           if(a[i]==a[j]){
                                  k[i]=a[j];    
                           }
                     }

              }

              for(int n=0;n<k.length;n++){
                     System.out.print(k[n]);
              }

       }
```

Comment: you shouldn't compare the numbers with the next in the list, you should for each number iterate over the new array. if the number 's already in there, don't add it, otherwise, add it.

Comment: Debug your code and you'll see your problem. It's highly recommended because you'll better understand the flow of your code. The debugger will change your life..

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested in finding the duplicates but only interested in removing them. the following approach would work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer[] a = new Integer[] {1,2,3,6,3,5,7,3,9,7};
        Set<Integer> numberset = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));
        Integer[] output = numberset.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        for (Integer i : output)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate your inner loop from `i+1` to length, change it to following.

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
   for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
      if(a[i]==a[j]){
         k[i]=a[j];    
      }
   }
}
```

The problem with your code is, It will check all the values at `a[i]` from 1 to n and will compare the values. It will be true for all `i` such that `1 <= i < n`.

Comment: but why.. i got this suggestion from one of my peer..but am not able to understand this..y i should use j=i+1?

Comment: @user3499450 Because you are covering till i in previous iterations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nice one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a={1,2,3,6,3,5,7,3,9,7};

    int[] k=new int[a.length];

    Set<Integer> dups = new HashSet<Integer>();

    int index = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        boolean found = false;
           for(int j=1;j<index && !found;j++){
                 if(a[i]==k[j]){
                     // found duplicate.
                     found = true;
                     dups.add(a[i]);
                 }
           }
           if (!found)
           {
               k[index++]=a[i];
           }

    }

    System.out.print("Unique entries: ");
    for(int n=0;n<index;n++){
        System.out.print(k[n]+" ");
 }

    System.out.println("\nDups:" + dups);
```

Output
`Unique entries:1 2 3 6 5 7 9`
`Dups:[3, 7]`

Comment: OP wants to print duplicates. This is printing uniques.